# dependency between oauth and sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, rubygems, omniauth

How to solve this dependency problem.
I`m using sorcery to administration and I dont need oauth2(0.4.1).

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "oauth2":
  In Gemfile:
    omniauth-facebook (>= 0) ruby depends on
      oauth2 (~> 0.5.0) ruby

    sorcery (>= 0) ruby depends on
      oauth2 (0.4.1)
```

This is my Gemfile

```
gem 'sorcery'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fork [the sorcery gem](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) and change [this line](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/Rakefile#L30) to be this:

```
gem.add_runtime_dependency 'oauth2', '~> 0.5.0'
```

Then make a commit, push it to GitHub and then reference it in your application like this:

```
gem 'sorcery', :git => "git://github.com/regedarek/sorcery.git"
```

For bonus points, submit that patch as a pull request to the original sorcery repository.

Comment: Thanks :)
I deleted my Gemfile.lock file and restart bundle install and and it has helped. But is this solution?

Comment: Done! I sent pull request to NoamB.